# Log4j warning: no appenders found even if it is there

Tags: java, spring, logging, log4j, log4j2

My project is in spring and for log configuration, I'm using log4j. The issue that I'm facing is that, I'm getting the following warning while starting the wildfly in the site server

```
18:06:42,630 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-7) log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
18:06:42,630 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-7) log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
18:06:42,630 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-7) log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

But the log4j2.xml file is there inside `project.war/WEB-INF/classes/` directory.
I couldn't simulate this problem in my local or in our servers because the same war is working fine without any problems.

sharing the java version of both places.

local:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_222-ea"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_222-ea-b03)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.222-b03, mixed mode)
```

Site:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_232"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_232-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.232-b09, mixed mode)
```

Sharing the `log4j2.xml` for your reference.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration monitorInterval="60">
  <Properties>
    <Property name="log-path">D:\Server\apache-tomcat-9.0.12\logs\</Property>
    <Property name="archive">${log-path}\\archive\\</Property>
  </Properties>
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console-Appender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>
                [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} (%F:%L) %X{TransactionId} - %msg%n
            </pattern>>
        </PatternLayout>
    </Console>
    <File name="File-Appender" fileName="${log-path}/data.log" >
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>
                [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} (%F:%L) %X{TransactionId}  - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
    </File>
        <RollingFile name="RollingFile-Appender"
                 fileName="${log-path}/data_back.log"
                 filePattern="${archive}/data.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm}.gz">
        <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] (%F:%L) %X{TransactionId} - %msg%n"/>
            <Policies>
                 <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
                 <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="30 MB"/>
            </Policies>
                 <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="30"/>
    </RollingFile>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>

       <Logger name="com.project" level="debug" additivity="false">
           <AppenderRef ref="File-Appender" level="debug"/>
           <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile-Appender" level="debug"/>
           <AppenderRef ref="Console-Appender" level="debug"/>
       </Logger> 
       <Logger name="com.project" level="debug" additivity="false">
           <AppenderRef ref="File-Appender" level="debug"/>
           <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile-Appender" level="debug"/>
           <AppenderRef ref="Console-Appender" level="debug"/>
       </Logger> 
        <Logger name="org.springframework" level="info" additivity="false">
           <AppenderRef ref="File-Appender" level="debug"/>
           <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile-Appender" level="debug"/>
           <AppenderRef ref="Console-Appender" level="debug"/>
       </Logger> 
       <Logger name="org.hibernate" level="info" additivity="false">
           <AppenderRef ref="File-Appender" level="debug"/>
           <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile-Appender" level="debug"/>
           <AppenderRef ref="Console-Appender" level="debug"/>
       </Logger>

    <Root level="info">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console-Appender"/>
    </Root>
 </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Please help me sort this out.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am updating this answer based on your comment below.

The log4j:warn messages are coming from Log4j 1.x. It is telling you that it cannot find any configuration. The configuration you show is for Log4j 2.

If you intend to use both Log4j 1 and Log4j 2 then you must provide a valid configuration for both. Do NOT try to log to the same files. In this scenario you should not have log4j-1.2-api.2.10.jar as that replaces log4j-1.2.17.jar.

If you only want to use Log4j 2 then remove the log4j 1.2.17 jar and leave  the log4j-1.2-api-2.10.0.jar from Log4j 2. You should also be using log4j-slf4j-impl-2.10.0.jar and not slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar. If commons logging is present then you should use log4j-jcl-2.10.0.jar.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I'm using 1.2.17. Sharing the jar details that I'm using

`log4j-1.2.17.jar
log4j-1.2-api-2.10.0.jar
log4j-api-2.10.0.jar
log4j-core-2.10.0.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar
commons-logging-1.2.jar`

Comment: I am glad it worked. It would be great if you accepted the answer since it worked for you.